# Filter for keyword in a set of keywords

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch 6.0+, I'd like to filter results by limiting them by one of the keyword fields, enforcing that this field be in a set of keywords.

Currently, I'm using `bool` as in this example:

```
GET users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "user_name": "alice"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {"match": {"country": "italy"}},
            {"match": {"country": "france"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but imagine there being 50 countries.

Is there some way to simplify this?  Something similar to Python's `country in ['italy', 'france']`?

Comment: How about this? [Terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @suparshva's comment, this can be rewritten:

```
GET users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "user_name": "alice"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "country": ["italy", "france"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```